How many tomatoes might be In a jar of tomato pasata(puree in America)?
I’m currently using a jar of uk ‘whole fruit’ tomato pasata(puree in US but including seeds and skin).  The jar says 410 grams.
I would imagine 4 large whole raw tomatoes weigh about 400 grams.
So would there be about just over 4 large tomatoes in a jar 410 gram jar of pasata?  I would expect the crushed product to look smaller since it’s crushed, however visually the jar still looks big for 4 large tomatoes making me wonder if there’s actually a lot more.
Thanks.

Passata has most of the liquid cooked out of it, so it'll contain more tomato per gram than pureed fresh tomatoes. But answering would be easier if we knew why you're asking. Are you trying to make passata? Substitute it for something?

@the-baby-is-you the pasata(puree in us) pictures is whole fruit and uncooked I.E raw.

@the-baby-is-you Tomato passata is not cooked down. Are you thinking of tomato paste?

It's not reduced/cooked down but it's far from raw. The shelf life indicates that if nothing else - but so does the flavour, which isn't that of raw tomatoes

@ChrisH what do you mean by it’s far from raw?  Can you explain what you suspect might have been done here as I’m thinking it is whole fruit raw uk puréed. I did contact h & b and they advised me as such though they may have misinformed me.

@JamesWilson uncooked tomatoes, pureed and not heated would keep for about 3 days in a fridge and not at all on the shelf. Does it have a pop up safety button in the cap ? They only work because of heat processing. Sources vary about the amount of processing involved but most involve a cooking step

... The absolute minimum for shelf life would be pasteurisation. Maybe they can say that's not hot enough to count as cooking, but it doesn't take much heat to make tomatoes taste non raw, and passata doesn't taste raw

1 medium-large tomato, pureed, measures about 1/2 cup in my experience. I just weighed one such tomato, and it weighed about 100g, so 410g would be approximately 4 tomatoes and should measure about 2 cups by volume. Notice that tomatoes generally don't have (much) air inside of them, so they don't lose volume when they are crushed.
Based on some volumetric calculations (assuming the passata inside the jar is cylindrical and has a volume of 2 cups), the jar would be about 12cm in diameter and the passata would reach about 26cm above the base of the jar. If that's the approximate size of your jar (plus or minus a bit because the jar isn't precisely cylindrical and I didn't take the time to model it as a cylinder plus a truncated cone), then it would follow that our original assumption of approximately 4 tomatoes per jar is correct.
